# GTest how to replace gtest_main with custom main

Tags: c++, qt, testing, googletest

I'm using GTest and GMock with Qt and some of the Qt components need to have a QGuiApplication created before they can be created, The QGuiApplication is usually created in the main so I have to replace the gtest_main with my custom main like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QGuiApplication guiApplication(argc, argv);
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

What's annoying now is that I need to do this in every test file. Is there a way to only define this once an reuse it for every test class?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to have one executable per file. Google  tests registration works thanks to the macro (TEST, TEST_F, TEST_P...) with a principle of inversion of control ( the test register to the factory, not the opposite),

so each tests in each compilation unit part of an executable automatically register to the main test factory.